# Start up script - ubuntu16

Tags: gnome, permissions, 16.04, scripts, startup

I am trying to write a script which will run at startup.
Issue is that I am trying to run this as root, on user login.
Could someone advise me which is the best way here?
I am on ubuntu-16, and I am having a hardtime.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: It should be a dupe, but to point you in the right direction, you'd need to tell us more about what the script should do.

Comment: What I am trying is this:- I have a ramdisk mounted by fstab which mounts under root ownership by default, I would like to modify ownership with user using a script during boot time. To make things worst I am using this mount point as as user home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible approach would be:

Create the script with just root acces (for safety sake)

```
sudo su
sudo echo 'echo "Hello world, I am `whoami`" > /tmp/test' > /path/to/script.sh
sudo chmod 700 /path/to/script.sh
```

Then change the sudoers file (according to mutliple tutorials everywhere)

```
sudo visudo
```

insert the following line at the end

```
youruser    ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

This grants your user to use the sudo command on exactly that script without password. This is the reason, why the root access permission is needed on the script - the script could get modified otherwise.

Now add a custom startup command with the command

```
sudo /path/to/script.sh
```

Check with the command

```
sudo cat /tmp/test
```

if it worked. the result should be

```
Hello World, I am root
```

Hope that helps and meets your requirements.

Comment: This would still be pretty unsafe, unless you store it on a location where it cannot be edited without adm permissions, *and* use the full path in the sudoers file.

Comment: As the file is created as root AND with access-rights 700 it is not possible for anybody else then root himself to change permissions or content of the file (I obviously missed the `sudo` at `chmod`, thanks for pointing out) . Furthermore, I used a fullpath in my example so I can not determine what you exactly mean with "and use the full path in the sudoers file"

Comment: addendum to @JacobVlijm : Obviuosly, it is a good idea to create the script in a folder structure dedicated to root, without permissions to write for anybody else. the biggest problem what happens if you don't do so is, that your script might gets moved by anybody (but not copied). One could define this as a security issue.  The file itself doesn't get accessible with this action though.

Comment: @wolfjuli : Thanks for your prompt help and detailing. This is fine and I think this is the best way to solve. I tried with adding a cron and initi scripts but this is the solution which worked. I have a user trying to login with his home as ramdisk, which is under root ownership since it is mounted via fstab. Instead of editing sudoers file I went to create a new file under sudoers.d and added my commands there, one of them is chown. Now all is good. Posting here so it can be useful to someone else as well.